# Is an RTOS required for DO-178B Level D Certification?

Tags: do178-b

Specifically what objectives are required to meet certification for Level D...which is only 'minor' criticality.

I can't seem to find anything, in the public, that points to what the objectives are for Level D.  I'm hopeful that a general purpose OS would meet whatever the criteria are.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** you must consult with a certification professional or with your certification authorities for getting a formal decision.

Since your question regarding the objectives for Level D is too general, I’ll focus only on operating system: DO-178B does not specify any requirement on an operating system. Actually an OS is considered just as any other software. Nevertheless, DO-178B does specify an objective, relevant also for Level D development, which OS can come handy: partitioning of resources (space and time) and confirming its integrity.

Comment: I believe my question was pretty darn specific.  Is a RTOS required to get certified at DO-178B Level D?  The fact that this question can't get answered is part of the problem with all of the DO-178B/C junk.  If it is up to someone's interpretation of Level D - well, what's the point?  In the end, I don't believe it it to be required.  But I've yet to decipher what 'partitioning' means within the scope of a 'general purpose' OS (e.g. Linux).